# passing axios response to child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

i'm developing a realtime search app. i have 3 component. Search, SearchBar and SearchResults. on every Change of input inside SearchBar, an event handler will execute. this function is passed from Search to SearchBar.
so on every change, parent component send a request to the server and fetch the data. then, parent pass them to it's child, SearchResults and SearchResults render them. but the problem is that **child component is always one step BEHIND**

for example, i typed sam. Search sent sam to the server and received the response. then passed them to SearchResults. but now it is rendering the response about "sa" instead of "sam"
if i type another s char, we have sams in search bar but SearchResults render the fetched data about "sam".

```
class Search extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.http = new Http();
    this.state = {phrase: ''};
    this.searchRes = null;
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('Search updated')
}

handleChange = async e => {
    await this.setState({
        phrase: e.target.value
    });
    console.log('state: '+this.state.phrase);
    this.sendPhrase();
};

sendPhrase() {
    return this.http.post('v1/search', {'phrase': this.state.phrase})
        .then(response =>
            this.searchRes = <SearchResults searchRes={response.data}/>
        );
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Col xs={12}>
                <SearchBar handleChange={this.handleChange} phrase={this.state.phrase}/>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12}>
                {this.searchRes}
            </Col>
        </>
    );
}
}
```

i appreciate your attention in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a component to rerender, you need to set state. A line like this does *not* cause the component to rerender:

```
this.searchRes = <SearchResults searchRes={response.data}/>
```

The only time you set state is when a change happens, and at that time, this.searchRes is set to whatever you set it to the last time a search finished. So you'll always render it with that last time.

The fix is to move the results into state:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.http = new Http();
  this.state = {
    phrase: '',
    results: null
  };
}

//...

sendPhrase() {
    return this.http.post('v1/search', {'phrase': this.state.phrase})
        .then(response => 
            this.setState({ results: response.data })
        );
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Col xs={12}>
                <SearchBar handleChange={this.handleChange} phrase={this.state.phrase}/>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12}>
                {this.state.results && (
                    <SearchResults searchRes={this.state.results}/>
                )}
            </Col>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you, i knew the first point but i didn't know the solution. actually i was in doubt (and i am). **passing such a big object to the state, doesn't cause any performance issue?** i'm new in react.

Comment: The size of the object is irrelevant. You're just passing a reference to it. It's not going to try to copy it or anything.

Comment: good point for a newbie. thanks! and the second problem is, with this approach Search component will rerender twice by every single change. and the second one is just for SearchResults rendering. is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you having performance problems? There are ways to limit rerenders, but don't reach for them unless you need them. If you do need them, then look up `shouldComponentUpdate`, and `PureComponent`.

Comment: i just wanna write code in an optimized way. so you as an expert in react, tell it doesn't matter that my component do an extra rerender. and it's Negligible **in General**. right? so i think i wanted to do a premature optimiztion. thank you so much!